# Jest mock nested function by using spyOn, but still call the actual function

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking, spyon

`getInfo` calls `getColor` in the same file. My intention is to mock `getColor` function, I import the func.js as a module and spyOn `getColor`. The mocked `getColor` is supposed to return "Red", but it still calls the actual function and returns "Black".

**Function File**

```
// func.js
function getColor() {
    return "black"
}

function getInfo(){
    const color = getColor()
    const size = "L"
    return `${color}-${size}`
}

module.exports = { getColor, getInfo }
```

**Test File**

```
// func.test.js
const func = require("./func")

describe("Coverage Change Test", () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    const colorMock = jest.spyOn(func, "getColor"); // spy on otherFn
    colorMock.mockImplementation(() => "Red");
  });

  afterAll(() => {
    colorMock.resetAllMocks();
  })

  test("return Large Red", async () => {
    const res = func.getInfo();
    expect(res).toEqual("Red-L");
  });
});
```

I also tried `requireActual`, but it also calls the actual one.

```
const { getInfo, getColor } = require('./func');

jest.mock('./func', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('./func.'),
  getColor: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => 'Red'),
}))

describe('test', () => {
  test('returns red', () => {
    const res = getInfo()
    expect(res).toEqual("Red-L")
  })
})
```

How can I properly mock up a nested function in Jest? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is natural limitation of JS. getColor is local variable and cannot be modified outside the scope it was defined (module scope).  Either treat these functions as 1 unit and test them altogether, or move them to separate modules, or consistently use them as methods on some object (`exports` like the answer suggested).

Comment: @EstusFlask Thanks for the reply. if I have `const color = await getColor()`, how to export an await function?

Answer (score 0):

You're spying on `func.getColor` and mocking its implementation but `getInfo` is calling the locally scoped `getColor` function. You have to change the way `getColor` is being called to be able to mock it.

```js
exports.getColor = function() {
  return 'black'
}

exports.getInfo = function() {
  const color = exports.getColor()
  const size = 'L'
  return `${color}-${size}`
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am not allowed to change the function code itself. Can we achieve it in the test file? thank you.

Comment: @Luke That's weird. You could use [rewire](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire) to override the `getColor` function in the test.

Comment: thank you so much. I guess my intention is I don't want to make a change to the code in order to create a unit test.

Comment: Rewire isn't supposed to be workable in Jest, they both hack module API and compete over it.

Comment: @Luke You should be cause you wrote regardless of how it will be tested, and this needs to be fixed.

Answer (score -1):

Use **[rewire](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire)** module to rewrite your exported properties.

Your test file will look like this:

```
const rewire = require('rewire')

describe('test', () => {
  let func;
  let getColorSpy;
  beforeEach(() => {
    getColorSpy = jest.fn()
    func = rewire(__dirname + '/func.js') // import
    func.__set__('getColor', getColorSpy) // rewrite content of getColor
  })
  test('should return Red-L when getColor returns Red', () => {
    getColorSpy.mockReturnValue('Red')

    const res = func.getInfo()

    expect(res).toEqual("Red-L")
  })
})
```

Try to avoid write code like your module.